# Generate a new variable based on two unequal data frames having similar item/value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two unequal data frames. Lets say
`A <- data.frame(x = 1:15, y=letters[1:15])` and
`B <- data.frame(k = 1:4, w=letters[1:4])`

I want to generate a new variable (`Z`) that equals `1`, if `y=w' otherwise` zero(0)`. that is want to generate a new variable that is equal to 1 if any text/description in the column "w" of data frame B, can be found in the column "y" of data frame A. Z will then be appended to data frame A. there are no common identifiers for the two datasets. I have this code and others and not working

```
A <- A %>%
  mutate(
    Z = if_else(
      y %in% B$w,
      '1',
      '0'
    )
  )
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.

Comment: @akrun It generated all 0s for me (which is not correct because i did check and there are similar variables). Besides i'm wondering if there is a better way to do it

Comment: For me it does create 1s for those values in 'B$w'.  Try on a fresh R session

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. my data is a text data though. Could it have anything to do with that?

Comment: If this is not the example you are testing, it should have been mentioned earlier.  My assumption was that this is the input.  Your data may not work due to multiple reasons i.e. if there is leading/lagging spaces, if there is a single character mismatch etc.  i.e. `%in%` is looking for fixed match on the whole string

Comment: right. the dataset is with spaces as said. the right data set is of the form.   `A <- c("Apple iPad", "", "Alexandra", "University of Boston", "Data entry", "Data entry clerk", "Tesla Cars", "managing director", "big data", "higher Salary")
B <- c("higher Salary", "negative review", "Data entry","big data", "Apple Ipad")`.         So I want to generate the new Z that equals 1 for any column where any entry in B can be found in A and zero for columns where it cannot be found. Any help with this?